# Facebook/Unity SDK basics

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have some basic questions that I couldn't figure out after searching for quite some time now. All tutorials and guides I've come across have the code already set up and I can't find them of much use. For instance, the Friend Smash example has the code integrated with buttons and other scripts that I can't use it in my own game.

I used Parse to upload my game and test it on facebook and it's working fine, but I want to add the social features to it (login, share, score etc.)

Picking up the code snippets that I'm supposed to use either brings me up errors (undefined variables etc.) or messes things up (I get the not-working, bugged login window on top of the running game inside Unity, while nothing happens if I build and run it).

Where am I supposed to put the code? For example:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Init
In the "Example" part, where am I supposed to put this line?
FB.Init(SetInit, OnHideUnity);

Same thing here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Feed
If I use the "Example" code as it is I get errors.

Do I have to use specific names for the scripts?

This is my first time uploading a game and trying to add social features to it so these questions may seem simple, but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your own class instead of "Example" class, where you put all your Facebook specific functions. Then you should invoke your methods with your own components, buttons, triggers, whatever.

It is also you, who should take care of pausing the game while running social functions (login, share etc.).

Comment: Yes I already made a class for my facebook-related code. Setting up some functions causes no problems, like this one:
`void Awake()
 {
  enabled = false;
  FB.Init (SetInit, OnHideUnity);
 }`
But, for example, to use the FB.Feed( link:"", linkName:""); I have no idea in which method to use it. The way I'm doing it now messes up the whole facebook thing ingame.

I also don't understand how to get the login window before entering the game, should I use a simple HTML page that has the facebook login button before loading the game after logging in?

Comment: You can prepare FacebookLogin scene, which should be your first scene, where you call the Login method. Then after successful login you can load another scene, with your game.

FBFeed methods are posting to facebook, you should call them automatically (not recommended) in some important moments of your game (new user level), or with use of special 'Share' button, which should be pressed by your users.